# How to prevent a key from functioning inside QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Suppose I have a text edit in my GUI interface, and i press a key like <kbd>a</kbd>, then i should not get 'a' written on my text edit.

I can add my own function to a key press event, but i cannot prevent it from doing the default mechanism.

Help me with this please.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the default `keyPressEvent` behaviour for a specific key, like this:

```
class CodeEditor(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A:
            # do nothing
            event.accept()
        else:
            # do the default
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install an eventFilter and prevent the key from being transmitted.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, Qt, QEvent

class Helper(QObject):
    def disable_key(self, w, key):
        self.m_w = w
        self.m_w.installEventFilter(self)

        self.m_key = key 
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.m_w and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == self.m_key:
                return True
        return QObject.eventFilter(self, obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    helper = Helper()
    view = QPlainTextEdit()
    helper.disable_key(view, Qt.Key_A)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

or by letter:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, Qt, QEvent

class Helper(QObject):
    def disable_key(self, w, letter):
        self.m_w = w
        self.m_w.installEventFilter(self)

        self.m_letter = letter 
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.m_w and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.text() == self.m_letter:
                return True
        return QObject.eventFilter(self, obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    helper = Helper()
    view = QPlainTextEdit()
    helper.disable_key(view, "a")
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```